# Compute the total memory used by Docker containers in Bash

Tags: bash, docker, sh

How to compute in one `Bash` command line the total memory used by `Docker` containers running on the local `Docker` engine?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I use the following command to compute the total memory used in MB.

```
docker stats --no-stream --format 'table {{.MemUsage}}' | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g' | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum "MB"}'
```

or if any are larger than 1GiB

```
docker stats --no-stream --format 'table {{.MemUsage}}' | sed 's/\.\([0-9]*\)GiB/\1MiB/g' | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g' | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum "MB"}'
```

Comment: `larger than 1GiB` only works if the memory usage has 3 decimal places, otherwise 1.33GiB becomes 133MiB

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr

```
docker stats --no-stream --format '{{.MemUsage}}' | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/GiB/ * 1024/;s/MiB//;s/KiB/ \/ 1024/' | bc -l | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Breaking this down:

`docker stats --no-stream --format '{{.MemUsage}}'` - Get only the memory usage

`awk '{print $1}'` - Strip the total memory from each line

`sed 's/GiB/ * 1024/;s/MiB//;s/KiB/ \/ 1024/'` - Normalize values into MiB

`bc -l` - Run calculations

`awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'` - Sum all lines

Comment: Use the following `sed` command if you want to end up with GiB:  
`sed 's/GiB//;s/MiB/ \/ 1024/;s/KiB/ \/ 1024^2/'`

Answer (score 4):

To get total memory regardless of container size --KiB, MiB, or GiB

`docker stats --no-stream --format 'table {{.MemUsage}}' | sed -n '1!p' | cut -d '/' -f1 | sed 's/GiB/ * 1024 MiB/;s/MiB/ * 1024 KiB/;s/KiB/ * 1024/; s/$/ +\\/; $a0' | bc | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B "$@"`

Comment: FYI `numfmt` is on Linux not on macOS